# How to set separate LaunchScreen storyboards for different targets in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project with multiple targets. Basically each target is a customized version of my app for different clients. I've tried customizing the Launch Screen File based on user defined fields in each target's build settings and then using that variable in the info.plist to determine which Launch Screen. I'd prefer to maintain one info.plist using user defined build settings if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By LaunchScreen you mean initial views rather than launch screen (iOS 8+ style launch storyboard that replaced static launch images). Correct?

EDIT: The OP indeed meant launch storyboards. These can be individually set to each targets as they are specified in the form of Info.plist option and each target can have its own Info.plist file.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the iOS 8+ storyboard that replaced launch images. When I assign the applicable storyboard xib to the target in the "General > Launch Screen File" section it saves it to every target. Then I have to remember to manually change it during build time. Ideally it would be nice to set it for the target and it simply remember it.

Comment: My storyboard launch screen simply has an image and some text. An ever better solution would be to programmatically decide which image and text to add to that storyboard.

Comment: OK. I've just tried it in my project and it works. Launch storyboard is UILaunchStoryboardName key in Info.plist. And Info.plist is can be set fro each target individually using INFOPLIST_FILE build option. Unfortunately, you can't do this programatically from code, as your app is not yet running when iOS displays your launch image/storyboard. That is the point of launch images.

Comment: So I would need a different info.plist for each target? I currently have one that is customized using user-defined build settings.

Comment: Yes. You should have separate .plists for targets already. It is the default config anyway and it makes sense to have them separated (unless you have made them universal by overriding INFOPLIST_FILE option). It is not a big deal, most of the .plist is generated by Xcode and or macro-driven. Alternatively you can use INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS to define expansions macros in Info.plist. Then you can continue using single file if you want to.

Comment: Maybe I just need to create multiple plist files for each target. I have each target sharing the same plist using the INFOPLIST_FILE option and that plist is customized based on user defined build settings for each target. I've tried using a #define UILaunchStoryBoardName "StoryBoard-xxx" where xxx is target code.

Answer (score 7):

You can also pick a different LaunchScreen on a per configuration basis, even within a single target.  Just set a variable in your .xcconfig files like

`LAUNCHSCREEN_NAME=launchscreen1`

And then in a single Info.plist you can set
`UILaunchStoryboardName` to `$(LAUNCHSCREEN_NAME)`

At build time, the selected configuration will determine which Launch Screen is used.